# How to make a link between two TableViews in Swift (IOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Please tell me how to develop two `UITableViews` that are linked with each other? if in `Tableview1` we select an item then second `Tableview` reload data accordingly
And how to load data into the tables, if they are in the same ViewController?
Maybe there are some examples..

Comment: There are some examples????? There are tons of them. Google is your answer. Have patient and search wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kampai said: plenty of examples on Google.

To help you a little bit in your search. Make sure you have a segue between the 2 TableViews, then in your first table view implement `prepareForSegue`, and in your second implement a function that searches for the right data, put it in an Array an use that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "idSecondTV" {            
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! mySecondViewController
        detailViewController.findStuff(parameter)
        ...
```